# Is it possible to make a house out of endersand?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If I mine endersand with a pickaxe, it drops cobblestone. Is there any way to mine, craft, or otherwise create endersand such that I can build a house out of it in the real world (not The End or The Nether)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will be able to mine Endersand with a "silk touch" enchanted pickaxe, which will cause it to drop actual Endersand blocks. ([Info](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ender_Sand), [more info](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting#Tool_Enchantments))

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can.

As of beta 1.9pre5, End Stone doesn't drop cobblestone anymore and can be mined with any old pickaxe, and pre6 added the ability to return from the End, so there's nothing stopping you from committing this crime against aesthetics.